# Bugs editing Examples when in "Retract & Edit" as well as "Edit" State

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor

### **Example Editor Bug**

Many times when retracting my edits to change addition sections, the area to make edits will not show up:

[image]

### **Briefly Explain Changes Comment Box Bug**

Secondly, the area where you are supposed to briefly describe your changes gets autopopulated with the entry I provided in my last example's edit. This means I lose my comments that I had made before I retracted my edit and cannot know what I changed when I retracted my edit. The autofill happens regardless of whether I have/have not edited an example.

This picture is to show the general area (of course I cannot prove to you that the autofilled comments have been autofilled or are not the correct comments, just trust me :D )

[image]

It should display my comments from when I originally made the edit and not display any comments if I am editing an example for the first time.

> I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome, Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit).